# SB-Admin Template Side bar active issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing this [Start Bootstrap SB Admin](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/) theme,
 which has a main `nav`, and a `submenu nav`.

it's not displayed active class background color and dashboard is always activated How to fix this issue, please help me to fix it?

look switched the `User` not display active back ground
[image: Click User not display active back ground]

This is my code sample
[look at my code](https://jsfiddle.net/w03a74ym/2/)

Thanks

Comment: There is more than one `.active`. Please also add some code here as a snippet

Comment: @ProEvilz sir, im try to add snippet, its getting some error, please check it https://jsfiddle.net/w03a74ym/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i fixed a my problem, i found some solution im added each page for `active` **class**  and   im showed `Collapsible List`  using `collapse show`

now it's working for me

[image: Work it's now]

```
<ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse show  " id="collapseUsers"> 
   <li class="active">
  <a href="userlist.html">Users List</a>
 </li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `li` element that contains the dashboard link has 2 classes: `nav-item` and `active`.

You can choose only **1** active sidebar item. Look for the sidebar item you want to change, and edit the **parent** `li` element's class from `class="nav-item"` to `class="nav-item active"`

Make sure you only have **one** sidebar link with the active class

Hope this helped.